# Bootcamp over external USB drive

Tags: bootcamp, external-disk

Is it possible to use boot camp on external drive? I would like to install windows on an SSD connected using USB 3.0 and boot from there. Has anyone done it ? Any problems with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boot Camp will not install to an external drive, (pg. 6)](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/boot_camp_install-setup_10.7.pdf) but you might be able to clone a Windows system to the external volume; not sure if a Mac will support booting it via USB 3.0 though.  I'd say you should wait for the next Boot Camp update which will likely bring USB 3 support (and hopefully native drivers for all the new Mac models introduced at WWDC 2012).